# Send mobile number on click button to the Server URL in Android

Tags: java, android, button, server

I want to make an app in which User Enter the mobile number then click on the proceed button the user mobile number send to the Server URL.here is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "Http Connection";
    private EditText mobileno;
    private Button proceed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mobilenumber);

        mobileno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        proceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncHttpTask asyncHttpTask = new AsyncHttpTask();
                final String url = "http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android";
                String MobileNo = mobileno.getText().toString();
                new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
            }
        });

    }


    public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting Proceed..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            Integer result = 0;
            try {
                /* forming th java.net.URL object */
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                String mobileNo = mobileno.getText().toString();
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                 /* optional request header */
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

                /* optional request header */
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

                /* for Get request */
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
                if (statusCode ==  200) {

                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                    String response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                    parseResult(response);

                    result = 1; // Successful

                }else{
                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {


            if(result == 1){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to fetch data!");
            }
        }
    }


    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line ;
        String result=null ;

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }

            /* Close Stream */
        if(null!=inputStream){
            inputStream.close();
        }

        return result;
    }
    private void parseResult(String result) {

        try{
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my xml file:

mobilenumber.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"

    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/boton"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="110dp"
            android:background="@drawable/logo"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your Number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:hint="        +91 Enter Number"

            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:background="#5fffffff"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />



    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="PROCEED"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/bright_foreground_inverse_material_light"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />




</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can pass mobileno at the time of calling async task like:                            new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url,mobileno);

Comment: It Show an error "cannot resolve method execute"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing the MobileNo while makin the server call.

To do so,

```
String MobileNo = mobileno.getText().toString();

final String url = "http://javatechig.com/api/get_category_posts/?dev=1&slug=android&mobile_no=" + MobileNo ;
```

Replace `mobile_no` with the appropriate parameter name.

Comment: Please provide code for any changes in Parseresult() Method

Comment: parseResult() method looks fine. If you face any problem, Please post your log cat errors.

Comment: when i tst the app it show an error "There is a problem parsing the package "

Comment: "There is a problem parsing the package" may occur because of the  minimum api level of the application is greater then the api level your phone currently have. Are you testing it in your phone?

Comment: hello Prokash the problem of manifest file is fine but when i install the in mobile then enter number and click on the button then button not work